# Find the matrix $f(A)$ for $f(z)=cos(3\pi z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Find the matrix $f(A)$ for $f(z)=cos(3\pi z)$
>   with $A =\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3& -5& 2\\ 1& 3& 1& -1\\ 1 &-1 &4 &-1\\-2& 2& -4& 4 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm taking a linear algebra course and this was one of the homework questions (studying for the final). Although there was no reference to which chapter this related to. I think I have to utilize generalized eigenvectors and the Jordan Canonical form, but I'm not exactly sure how.

If I were to use J.C. Form, my characteristic polynomial would be $f(\lambda)=(\lambda -2)(\lambda - 3)^3$, so my eigenvalues are $\lambda=2,3$. 
Then the $Nul(A-2I)=Span\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$. But then I believe $Nul(A-3I)=Span\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 3\\0\\-1\\2 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$? (I think)...
Is this way I should start this?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the Taylor expansion for $F(z)$?  If you can do this, then simply "plug-in" $A$..... you already know how to compute scalar multiples and powers of a matrix.

Comment: Each eigenspace of a real eigenvalue is at least one-dimensional. Perhaps you’ve made a transcription error with $\operatorname{span}(0)$?

Comment: @Squirtle I completely forgot about that method, and I even have some examples in my notes on how to carry out that. Definitely what I was looking for!

Comment: @amd You're right, I went through my work and found my mistake. Thanks for that!

Comment: Once you have the Jordan matrix, I suggest decomposing it further into the sum of a diagonal and nilpotent matrix. If you’ve done it right, they commute, which should make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $A=QFQ^{-1}$ where $F=diag(2,3I_3+J)$, where $J$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $3$. Then $f(A)=Qf(F)Q^{-1}$.

The conclusion comes from the calculation of $Q$ and

$f(F)=diag(f(2),f(3I+J))$ with  $f(3I+J)=f(3I)+f'(3)J+(1/2)f''(3)J^2$.